# File create in native code gives permission denied

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my Android project, I can create a file on sdcard from my Java code just fine. However, when I try to create a file from the native code, I get a permission denied error. Here is the code snippet:

```
void dumpToFile(const void* buf, int bufLen, const char* fileName) {
   char fullPath[4096];
   sprintf(fullPath, "/sdcard/Download/%s", fileName);
   int fd = ::open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 00664);
   if (fd < 0) {
     LOGE("Couldn't open file. Error: %s", strerror(errno));
     return;
   }
   ...
}
```

The directory download exists on the sdcard. I also have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions set in the manifest.

Is there something that I am missing? Regards.

Comment: What is the path you are using?

Comment: Change your `LOGE` to print `fileName` as well.  What does it show?  Also, it would be best to retrieve the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` value rather than hardcoding `/sdcard/`.

Comment: Thank you all. The code is show is the simplified version. I am using getExternalStorageDirectory(). The actual path is "/storage/sdcard0/MyAppName/MyFile.bin." I have also verified that "/storage/sdcard0/MyAppName" folder exists.